# Analysis of PSOLA

Tags: pitch, overlap-add

I'm reading the original paper on [PSOLA](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/016763939090021Z) (Pitch-Synchronous Overlap-Add), and am struggling with equation (2), in which the authors analysed the effect of a simple pitch-and-time-scale modification on a stationary noise process $n(m)$, which is super-positioned on a periodic signal $d(m)$ with period $P$.

Here, the analysis window size can be assumed to be integer multiples of $P$, with hop size $P$, with the constant overlap assumption satisfied.

Denoting the pitch modification factor by $\beta$, the time-scale modification factor by $\gamma := \beta$, the original noise process by $n(m)$, the analysis window by $h(m)$ and the synthesis noise signal by $\tilde{n}(m)$, equation (2) states:
\begin{align}
    \tilde{n}(m) &= \sum_s h(s\beta P - m)n(m - s \beta P + s P) \tag{2a} \\
                 &= \tilde{R}(\tau) = \frac{1}{\beta P} \sum_{k=0}^{\beta P - 1} E(\tilde{n}(k)\tilde{n}(k-\tau)) \tag{2b} \\
\tilde{R}(\tau) &= \frac{1}{\beta P} \sum_{m} \rho(\tau - m\beta P) R(\tau + m(1- \beta P)). \tag{2c}
\end{align}
where $\tilde{R}(\tau)$ and $R(\tau)$ denote the original and synthesized noises' auto-correlation, and $\rho(\tau):=h(t)*h(-t)$ is the analysis window auto-correlation.

Indeed all three of the equalities stated here baffled me. Specifically,

1. In (2a), why is the window $h(.)$ flipped such that it's not $h(m - s\beta P)$?
2. In (2a), why is the noise term $n(m - s \beta P + sP)$ and not just $n(m - s\beta P)$?
3. Given that we are modifying both the pitch and time by the same factor, why don't we simply have $\tilde{n}(m)=n(m/\beta)$ and indeed $\tilde{d}(m)=d(m/\beta)$?
4. In (2b), Why is the synthesized noise $\tilde{n}(R)$ equal to the autocorrelation $\tilde{R}(\tau)$?
5. How does (2c) come about?

Note that the paper provides the following footnote to explain this equation:

> $\tilde{n}(m)$ is not a WSS (Wide sense stationary) process, but a WS (Wide-sense) cyclostationary process. This means that the autocorrelation sequence $R(t_1, t_2) = E(\tilde{n}(t_1)\tilde{n}(t_2))$ is not invariant on the diagonal of $t_1-t_2$ plane, but is nevertheless periodic=: $R(t_1 + m\beta P, t_2 + m\beta P) = R(t_1, t_2)$. However, there is a close relationship between WS stationary and WS cyclostationary processes: it can be demonstrated that if the time origin is subject to a random shift $\theta(t)$ that varies sufficiently slowly, then the resulting process $\tilde{n}(t)=\tilde{n}(t - \theta{t}))$ is WS stationary (Papoulis, 1984). The autocorrelation sequence of this process is equal to the "time-average autocorrelation" of process $\tilde{n}(m)$.

which is still cryptic to me.

### Reference

Papoulise, A. (1984). *Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes*, McGraw-Hill, NY

Comment: Line (2b) looks like an error. I (erroneously) removed the leading = sign, but the original paper has it so I reverted my change.  I can't see how it can be true that $\tilde{n}(m) = \tilde{R}(\tau)$.

Answer (score 2):

Attempts to answer you series of questions:

> 1. In (2a), why is the window $h(.)$ flipped such that it's not $h(m - s\beta P)$?

The paper (p455) states:

> The windows $h_m(n)$ are of Hanning type$\ldots$

so they're symmetric and whether it's $h(t)$ or $h(-t)$ doesn't matter because $h(t) = h(-t)$.

> 2. In (2a), why is the noise term $n(m - s \beta P + sP)$ and not just $n(m - s\beta P)$?

I'm not exactly sure, but I suspect it's to do with Figure 2 of the paper.

[image: Showing intermediate step between analysis and synthesis]

I think the equation is showing the overall effect of going from analysis timescale to intermediate timescale to synthesized timescale.

> 3. Given that we are modifying both the pitch and time by the same factor, why don't we simply have $\tilde{n}(m)=n(m/\beta)$ and indeed
>    $\tilde{d}(m)=d(m/\beta)$?

Because that only modifies the time, not the pitch.

> 4. In (2b), Why is the synthesized noise $\tilde{n}(R)$ equal to the autocorrelation $\tilde{R}(\tau)$?

I think that's an error. You can see in the original equation (2) that there is a comma at the end of the first line.  I think the leading = sign on the second line shouldn't be there.

[image: Original equation 2]

> 5. How does (2c) come about?

That's just substituting your (2a) into your equation (2b) (neglecting what I believe to be the erroneous leading =) and applying the expectation operator and the expression for $\rho$:

$$
\rho(\tau) = h(t) \star h(-t)
$$

Comment: Thanks for attempting this. Your suggestion that (2c) arises from substituting (2a) into (2b) seems correct, although this raises further question on why it is $R(\tau + m(1- \beta P))$ and not simply $R(\tau)$. Further justification on why all the off-diagonal terms (in the multiplication of the two sums) are ignored is also needed given that the windows are overlapping. Likewise why $\rho(\tau - m \beta P)$ and not $\rho{\tau}$?

Comment: I'm also unsure about your answer to question (3). Having $\tilde{n}(m/\beta)$ is I suppose equivalent to a resampling of $n(m)$, which would change *both* pitch and tempo by the same factor. To preserve pitch but to scale up the tempo, one would naturally have $\tilde{x}(m) = \sum_s x(m - s\beta P)$, which I think is explained in section 1.4 of the paper.

Comment: @TimMak Regarding (2c) : This is because we're trying to find $\tilde{R}(\tau)$ in terms of $R(\tau)$. And the definition of $\tilde{n}(m)$ cyclically extends $n(m)$, which will mean that $\tilde{R}(\tau)$ will cyclically extend $R(\tau)$.

Comment: @TimMak Regarding (3) : Simple because that's not how they've defined the relationship between $\tilde{n}(m)$ and $n(m)$. There is that cyclical extension relationship between them, not just time scaling.